# Bonding 2 interfaces on my storage with different speed

Tags: networking, storage

On my synology storage I have bonding option. I am not sure if it is right to do that way, so if you can help me :) So my synology have 2 ports , 1x10G and 1x1G and i am thinking to bond them. Will the speed decrease on the lower one ? Or the synology will operate on the 10g port ? In the networking options the bond interfaces says that operates on 10 000MBPS but when I open info center there shows 1GBPS.. So I am confused :D Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get Active/backup so I want the storage to operate on the 10gbps but when the sfp fails or something happen with the interface to activate the backup interface 1gbps. So there is no downtime

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://kb.synology.com/en-ca/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/connection_network_linkaggr?version=7)? If so, [edit] your question to explain what is unclear from the documentation.